# Does botium do partial matching?

Tags: automated-tests

How can we do partial matching in botium testing?
It passes the test cases only when the expexted and bot response matches 100%. I want it to match even there is 90% match. can we do this in Botium?

Answer (score 0):

No. A test run is considered as passed if and only if all test cases pass - any other approach would make no sense. Botium supports several different [matching modes](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/Botium-Configuration#scripting_matching_mode) as well as [utterances matching](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/Botium-Scripting) - usually it is possible to do all kind of text assertions. If not, you can even add your own asserter code (Javascript coding required).
So the best thing you can do is redesign your test cases to make them more robust.